# Ordenação SQL apenas depois do terceiro caracter

Tags: php, mysql, classificação

Tenho um campo em minha tabela no MySQL que é do tipo string, com os seguintes dados:

```
Coluna
01DV
03DV
04DV
```

Se inserir o valor `02CA` o campo finca assim

```
Coluna
01DV
02CA
03DV
04DV
```

Eu preciso que ele fique assim:

```
Coluna
02CA
01DV
03DV
04DV
```

como faço isso em MySQL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caso queira ordenar primeiro pelas letras do exemplo, mas manter a ordem numérica:

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY SUBSTRING(nome, 3), nome
```

Que praticamente dá no mesmo que

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro ORDER BY SUBSTRING(nome, 3), SUBSTRING(nome, 1, 2)
```

A sintaxe do `substring` é: `substring( caractere inicial, quantidade )`.

Comment: Obs: Usei 3 com base no que foi perguntado. Ajuste para o tamanho correto da string, caso ela tenha espaços iniciais.

Answer (score 4):

***Assim:***

```
SELECT coluna
FROM (SELECT coluna, substring(coluna, 3) coluna1 FROM tabela4) AS T 
ORDER BY T.coluna1, T.coluna
```

*Exemplo:* [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cd4d0/3)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui é só fazer ustilizar o `substring` combinado com `order by` como no exemplo abaixo.

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE 1 order by SUBSTRING(nome,5)
```

Desta maneira ele ordena depois do 5º caracter.

Comment: Cuidado. desta maneira pode acontecer de aparecer 04DV antes de 01DV